# working with folders with SharePoint phpSPO library

Tags: php, sharepoint

I'm working with phpSPO library for work with sharePooint in a PHP app.
https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

For example, I retrieve the files of an specific folder

```
try {

    $authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($Settings['Url']);
    $authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($Settings['UserName'],$Settings['Password']);
    // conecction successfull  

   $folderUrl = "/sites/mySite/Tfts/eiic";

    $url = $Settings['Url'] .  "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{$folderUrl}')/Files";
   $request = new RequestOptions($url);
   $ctx = new ClientContext($url,$authCtx);
   $data = $ctx->executeQueryDirect($request);

  // HOW to Convert $data to FolderItem or Folder class ??

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

In the example above, $data is a JSON with the folder files but, How can I convert this JSON to a File or FileCollection for working with its properties?

Another Question, How to Upload a file to a specific folder ??

Thank u very much !

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to target entities such as [`File`](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/src/SharePoint/File.php) and [`Folder`](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/src/SharePoint/Folder.php) when dealing with SharePoint resources.

In that case the example for getting files under a specific folder could be converted to:

```
$files = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl($parentFolderUrl)->getFiles();
$ctx->load($files);
$ctx->executeQuery();
//print files info
foreach ($files->getData() as $file) {
    print "File name: '{$file->getProperty("ServerRelativeUrl")}'\r\n";
}
```

---

Let's say your site has the following structure:

```
Documents (library) 
|
---   Archive (folder)
      |
      --- 2001 (folder)
```

then the below example demonstrates how to upload file into `2001` sub folder:

```
$targetFolderUrl = "/Documents/Archive/2007";
$localPath = "./User Guide.docx";

$fileName = basename($localPath);
$fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
$fileCreationInformation->Content = file_get_contents($localPath);
$fileCreationInformation->Url = $fileName;

$uploadFile = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetFolderUrl)->getFiles()->add($fileCreationInformation);
$ctx->executeQuery();
```